@mediapipe/tasks-vision/vision_bundle.mjs Module parse failed: Unexpected token (30:18) in React.js
Giving compilation error while running how to resolve this ?
`Failed to compile.
./node_modules/@mediapipe/tasks-vision/vision_bundle.mjs 30:18
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (30:18)
File was processed with these loaders:

./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
| function c(t) {


if (h) t = (a ||= new TextEncoder()).encode(t);else {
|     let n = 0;
|     const r = new Uint8Array(3 * t.length);
`

Added webpack.config.js file
 // webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}; 

Added .babelrc file
 // .babelrc
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
    ]
  }
  

Install packages needed:
npm install webpack webpack-cli babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react --save-dev


